# how to weight an histogram with gradient?

Tags: matlab, histogram, gradient, convolution

i'm trying to build a color histogram descriptor following
[this paper](http://users.cecs.anu.edu.au/~jdomke/papers/2006bmvc.pdf)... It weights the color of the image with a map.. this map is obtained computing the gradients of the image in two color channels, the first one is red, the second is the mean between green and blue.  First of all i'm trying to obtain the results shown in figure 1 but without success...Maybe i've not understood this approach but it sounds easy....This is my code:

```
    %Lowpass
h = fspecial('gaussian');
I = imfilter(img,h);

I1 = img(:,:,1);
I2 = img(:,:,2);
I3 = img(:,:,3);

F = I1;
G = (I2 + I3)/2;

dx = [-1; 0; 1];
Fx = conv2(F,dx,'same');
Gx = conv2(G,dx,'same');

dy = [-1 0 1]; 
Fy = conv2(F,dy,'same');
Gy = conv2(G,dy,'same'); M = abs(Fx.*Gy - Fy.*Gx);
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't read through the entire paper, but as far as I understand the mask `M` you compute seems correct.

Again without too much confidence, I think each element of this mask is a 'weight' for the 'color' of the corresponding pixel. The color is interpreted as a 3-dimensional coordinate in the RGB space, and the paper indicates that they resolved each color channel with only 5 bins, resulting in a 5x5x5 matrix or 125 colors histogram.

The process that you didn't write in your code is the actual binning of the weights. For this task, you cannot simply use `hist` or `histc` because although bins are specified by their color, the contribution of each pixel with that color is different. I think in this case you need the function `accumarray` in order to bin the weights to their respective color bin. Assuming that the color values run in `[0,1]`, here is your histogram:

```
C = 1 + floor( (5-1e-15)*[I1(:),I2(:),I3(:)] ); % put colors in {1,2,3,4,5}
H = accumarray( C, M(:), [5,5,5] );
```

Comment: Yes you're right... i gonna try your method but i need few clarifications on your use of accumarray:

1) you cast float values from double [0 1] to int [1 5], why you use (5-eps) instead of just 5?
2) then, you put all three channels value into one array C and apply accumarray but i've not clear the meaning of how you run this function... M(:) should be an array and C is an array with length = 3*length(M(:))... how do you multiply the values of C with the weights  in M(:)?
3) and if my range was [0 255] or if i have different ranges for each channel? (such as in YCbCr or Lab)

Comment: I've processed I1 I2 and I3 with im2double and tried your solution but I got an error: 
Error using accumarray
First input SUBS and third input SZ must satisfy ALL(MAX(SUBS)<=SZ).

Comment: 1) I want values in the range [0,5), not [0,5], otherwise I would need 6 bins. 2) Sorry if it sounds rude, but the best answer is to read the documentation of [`accumarray`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html). 3) Then divide by 255 and/or adapt for each channel. 4) It looks like the intensities aren't in the right range, cf 3).

Comment: of course i've read the documentation, but i will again with more care... about the above error i didn't understand your suggestion but max(C(:)) returns 6

Comment: Paste your code in the OP or ask another question, without the code and the associated error, we're not going anywhere.

Comment: Then you did not solve anything; if you are using (4-eps) they should be between 1 and 4...

Comment: i checked.. using (4-eps) the values are from 1 to 5... it's wrong?... I(:) ranges in [0 1]

Comment: after the above code i insered the following:

    M = abs(Fx.*Gy - Fy.*Gx);    
    
    I1 = im2double(I1);
    I2 = im2double(I2);
    I3 = im2double(I3);
    
    C = 1 + floor( (4-eps)*[I1(:),I2(:),I3(:)] );

then if i run 

>> min(C(:))
ans =
     1
>> max(C(:))
ans =
     5

Comment: For goodness sake, this is nonsense, check the range of your image intensities **beforehand**! Is this the first time you need to rescale an image?

Comment: Sorry but i think that if you say that it is nonsense you should tell me why?.... i think that the pixels of I(:) that have value 1 are multiplied with (4-eps) that is like 4.9999.... and then these number are processed by floor() obtaining 4, plus 1 give 5. is that nonsense? and if.. why?

Comment: (4-eps) is 3.999... And that is not the problem; you should know the range of intensity values for each color channel, there is no magic formula for this (could be [0,1], {0,255} or 12 bits values if you're dealing with CT images, or anything, I can't guess!). Once you know that, normalize it between 0 and 1 (this is NOT equivalent to dividing by the max of each channel, we're talking absolute max here, not relative), and ONLY THEN use the scaling I wrote above.

Comment: yes you're right... but as i've said i process the channels with  im2double(I1) and they have values in [0 1].... it is really nonsense

Comment: maybe i've understand... if i look at the max of I1 I2 and I3 get  max([I1(:),I2(:),I3(:)])
ans =
    1.0000    0.9647    0.9804
then multiplying with 4-eps
(4-eps)*max([I1(:),I2(:),I3(:)])
ans =
    4.0000    3.8588    3.9216
and that is because (4-eps) is equal to 4.. so the value 1 is mapped to 5 and the value 0 is mapped to 1... is the quantization correctly done in the range [1 5] also in this way?

Comment: Be careful with the representations used for printing: '3.99999' will be rounded off to '4.0000' with the format '%.4f'. What does `max(floor( (5-eps)*[I1(:),I2(:),I3(:)] ))` and `max([I1(:),I2(:),I3(:)]) <= 1` give?

Comment: >> max(floor( (5-eps)*[I1(:),I2(:),I3(:)] ))
ans =
     5     4     4
>> max([I1(:),I2(:),I3(:)]) <= 1
ans =
     1     1     1
so now it appears working... right?
i'm a bit confused.... is it right if i usesd directly something like 4.9999?

Comment: Hm, how weird! I just checked on Matlab and `floor(5-eps)` returns 5, this is absurd! Well, use `(5-1e-15)` instead I guess. :)

Comment: Again, be careful with the string representation. But the answer is yes, just put as many 9s as you need for the precision you expect in the intensity values. This is why I prefer the notation `5-1e-5`, your precision is clear.